# Dynamically create table in the database from a map using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I need help for this problem. I have a map of values:

```
$table = "tableName"
$columns = "col1", "col2", ... "coln"
$types = "col1type" .... "colntype"
```

Is it possible to use PDO Prepared statements to build a SQLITE query like this(example):

```
create table if not EXISTS 'tableName' ('col1' TEXT, 'col2' TEXT, ... , 'coln' TEXT);
```

of course not knowing in advance how many bind params I need to use, I would need a prepared statements template like this:

```
create table if not EXISTS ':tableName' (':col1Name' :col1Type, ':col2Name' :col2Type, ... , 'colnName' :colnType);
```

I was thinking of building the query by first concatenating the prepared statement:

```
$query = " create table if not EXISTS ':tableName' (";

for($i=0; i<count($columns); i++){
$query = $query . " ':col$iName' " . " :col$iType ";

if($i != count($columns) - 1){
$query = $query . ",";
}else {
$query = $query . ")";
}
}
```

then bind the params in another for cycle.
I don't like this solution much, so I am asking if there is a better way of doing this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where do you get this map from?

Comment: I don't have the code, but I intend to extrapolate this information from a JSON

Comment: Where does this json come from?

Comment: It come from the database, I need to map some  keys and values as tablename and columns and determine the type on a per base case. Anyway, I don't think it's important where it comes from and why, I need to work with that JSON and create a table using some parameters.

Comment: You cannot use parameters with create table.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question :)